# getFolderById works fine in apps editor, but won't in related spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, authorization, google-oauth

I have a spreadsheet which aims to generate invoices. One sheet per invoice, and some checkboxes to manage the content. One of them is designed to save sheet as pdf file into a dedicated folder of the GDrive of the same account.
Here is my code:

`function saveInvoiceIntoGDrivePDF() {`
    `const currentSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`
    `const paramSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Paramètres généraux");`
    `const currentSheet = currentSpreadSheet.getActiveSheet();`
    `const invoicesStorageFolderOnGDriveId = paramSheet.getRange('B30').getValue();`
    `DriveApp.getFolderById(invoicesStorageFolderOnGDriveId);   const authorizationToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();`
    `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Got Auth Token!");`
    `const exportLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+currentSpreadSheet.getId()+"/export?format=pdf&size=a4&portrait=true&scale=4&top_margin=1.00&bottom_margin=1.00&left_margin=0.50&right_margin=0.50&gridlines=false&printnotes=false&pageorder=2&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&fzr=false&fzc=false&attachment=false&r1=0&r2=40&c1=1&c2=6&gid="+currentSheet.getSheetId();`
    `const invoicingYear = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J5').getValue();`
    `const invoicingMonth = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N6').getValue();`
    `const customerName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J9').getValue();`
    `const indexFacture = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J7').getValue();`
    `const invoicePDFFileName = "Invoice_"+invoicingYear+"_"+invoicingMonth+"_"+customerName+"_"+indexFacture+".pdf";`
    `const exportParams = {     method:"GET",     headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+authorizationToken},     muteHttpExceptions:true   };`
    `var invoicePDFContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, exportParams).getBlob().setName(invoicePDFFileName);`
    `invoicesStorageFolderOnGDrive.createFile(invoicePDFContent);`
`}`

Set authorizations into appsscript.json as following:

`{`
    `"timeZone": "Europe/Paris",`
    `"dependencies": {`
    `},`
    `"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",`
    `"runtimeVersion": "V8",`
    `"oauthScopes": [`
        `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",`
        `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",`
        `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",`
        `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"`
    `]`
`}`

This function, like many others, is triggered by a checkbox in the "management area" of each sheet, with the label "Save as PDF in Drive".

The problem is that this function works like a charm when running it from the Apps scripts editor, but won't gather drive permissions from the appsscript.json.

I understand there are limitations on authorizations, but what I can't figure out is that, as the script projet is (from my understanding) *attached* to the spreadsheet, why it can run from the editor but not from the spreadsheet it has been designed for? What is the interest to allow to write a script which won't work in "real world"?

And, if this is a strong authorization issue, is there a way to have Google "accept" this script, as it only creates new files in the same account it belongs to?

Any help appreciated,
Many thanks,
Emmanuel

Tried all I could from documentation and forums (but could hardly get "outdated" posts).

The issue is that this spreadsheets is to be run by people whith little computers knowledge, and for the moment, they have to:

1. Click on the "open pdf in a separate tab"
2. Download pdf setting the name manually
3. Upload file from their computer to GDrive

This is (obiously) painful from their point of view, and very little satisfying as this is the very last straight line of my "application".

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is likely that the issue is not with your `saveInvoiceIntoGDrivePDF()` function but the code that _runs_ that function. Please show that code as well as it is quite relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> checkboxes to manage the content. One of them is designed to save sheet as pdf

It sounds like you are using an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to run the `saveInvoiceIntoGDrivePDF()` function.

`onEdit(e)` runs in a context where it cannot access any personal information nor call services that would require authentication. All `DriveApp` methods require authentication, so they cannot be called from `onEdit(e)`.

To make it work, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of a simple trigger, or run the `saveInvoiceIntoGDrivePDF()` function through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), or a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars).

Comment: Interesting. Do you mean an installable trigger which raises on an edition on my spreadsheet will work whereas the default one is curbed?

Comment: Another point which might be a "wrong bias": I initially thought about using a sidebar to host the managing features, as management area is copied to each invoice sheet, but I was under the impression that the sidebar would be less "standard" than a function directly linked to a cell, and hence would work more or less depending on the used browser. Am I wrong?

Comment: A simple trigger runs without authorization which limits what it can do. An installable trigger is authorized by the user who creates the trigger, and when the trigger fires, the code runs under the account of the user who created the trigger rather than the account of the user at the keyboard. If you use a sidebar, menu item or button, the code runs under the account of the user at the keyboard, and they will have to go through the authorization flow the first time they run the code.